# Making content list without linebreaks

Tags: table-of-contents, lists, memoir

[Edited to simplify and update the question following a comment]

I would like to make content list at the beginning of the document, that contains section titles and a list of keywords, that is in-line with a specific format. Here is a minimal example thus far:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,onecolumn,oneside]{memoir}
\usepackage[marginparwidth=2cm,textwidth=18.5cm,textheight=26cm]{geometry} % X
\usepackage[danish]{babel}
\usepackage[danish]{isodate}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{multicol}

\makechapterstyle{Minimal}{%
    \renewcommand*{\printchaptername}{}
    \renewcommand*{\chapternamenum}{}
    \renewcommand*{\chapnumfont}{}
    \renewcommand*{\printchapternum}{}
    \renewcommand*{\afterchapternum}{}
    \setlength{\beforechapskip}{0pt}
    \setlength{\midchapskip}{0pt}
    \setlength{\afterchapskip}{20pt}
}

\titleformat{\section}[runin]{\bfseries}{}{0pt}{}[~~]
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}
\cftpagenumbersoff{section}

\titleformat{\subsection}[runin]{\bfseries}{}{0pt}{}[~~]
\titlespacing{\subsection}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}
\cftpagenumbersoff{subsection}

\newcommand{\bigpar}{\vspace{1em}}

\newcommand{\Word}[1]{%
    {{\bfseries#1}\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{#1}}
}
\setsecnumdepth{chapter}
\newcommand*{\setupparasubsecs}{%
\let\oldnumberline\numberline
\renewcommand*{\cftsubsectionfont}{\itshape}
\renewcommand*{\cftsubsectionpagefont}{\itshape}
\renewcommand{\l@subsection}[2]{%
    \def\numberline####1{\textit{####1}~}%
    \leftskip=\cftsubsectionindent
    \rightskip=\@tocrmarg
%% \advance\rightskip 0pt plus \hsize % uncomment this for raggedright
%% \advance\rightskip 0pt plus 2em    % uncomment this for semi-raggedright
    \parfillskip=\fill
    \ifhmode ,\ \else\noindent\fi
    \ignorespaces{\cftsubsectionfont ##1}~{\cftsubsectionpagefont##2}%
    \let\numberline\oldnumberline\ignorespaces}
}
%\AtEndDocument{\addtocontents{toc}{\par}

\newcommand*{\setupmaintoc}{%
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{\vspace{-1.2cm}}
\let\changetocdepth\oldchangetocdepth
\let\precistoctext\oldprecistoctext
\let\cftchapterfillnum\oldcftchapterfillnum\addtodef{\cftchapterbreak}{\par}{}
\renewcommand*{\cftchapterfont}{\normalfont\sffamily}
\renewcommand*{\cftchapterleader}{%
    \sffamily\cftdotfill{\cftchapterdotsep}}
\renewcommand*{\cftchapterafterpnum}{}
\renewcommand{\cftchapterbreak}{\par\addpenalty{-\@highpenalty}}
\setpnumwidth{2.55em}
\setrmarg{3.55em}\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}}
\let\cftpartformatpnum\oldcftpartformatpnum
\addtodef{\cftpartbreak}{\par}{}
\let\cftbookformatpnum\oldcftbookformatpnum\addtodef{\cftbookbreak}{\par}{}
%\setupparasubsecs

\begin{document}
\mainmatter
\chapterstyle{Minimal}

\chapter*{Title}
\begin{multicols}{2}

\setupmaintoc
\tableofcontents*
\end{multicols}
\section{Section title 1} - Date: 01.01.2011

Lorem ipsum dolor sit \Word{amet}, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in \Word{voluptate} velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
\subsection{Ut enim ad minim veniam:} Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis \Word{nostrud} exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in \Word{reprehenderit} in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non \Word{proident}, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

\section{Section title 2} - Date: 02.01.2011

Lorem ipsum dolor sit \Word{amet}, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in \Word{voluptate} velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 

Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis \Word{nostrud} exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in \Word{reprehenderit} in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non \Word{proident}, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

\section{Section title 3} - Date: 03.01.2011

Lorem ipsum dolor sit \Word{amet}, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in \Word{voluptate} velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 

Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis \Word{nostrud} exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in \Word{reprehenderit} in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non \Word{proident}, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
```

The list looks like this:

[image]

I would like it to look like this:

[image]

I have tried to follow the memoir manual section 9.2.5. The two commented out pieces of code are from that.

The commented out bits give the following errors:

```
\setupparasubsecs
```

"Parameters must be numbered consecutively. [\setupparasubsecs]"
"You can't use `macro parameter character #' in horizontal mode. [\setupparasubsecs]"

```
\AtEndDocument{\addtocontents{toc}{\par}
```

TeX STOPPED: File ended while scanning use of \AddToHook{\addtocontents {toc}{\par } \par \newcommand *{\setupmaintoc }{\renewcommand
TeX reports the error was in file: minimalexample.tex

Comment: I'm finding it more and more difficult to understand my code, never mind others. I think that the `memoir` manual might help section **9.2.5 Example Multiple contents** and in particular the code for `\setupparasubsecs` which sets `\subsection` titles in the ToC as a comma deliminated paragraph (as shown the the manual's full ToC). Perhaps you could change your `\W/word` macros to put a modified `\subsubsection` title into the ToC, remembering to turn off ToC subsubsection page numbers.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have looked at that section multiple times before, but I only know what it does now, because you've told me. I get that looking at other peoples code can be tedious, but I often find the code in the manual less comprehensible than someones practical translation of it. But I made an attempt, and have tried the code in 9.2.5 'as is' by copying the code into my minimal example document. I have updated (and simplified) my minimal example to work towards the solution you've suggested and included the errors I get when I try to run the code from the manual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said my LaTeX skills are rapidly decreasing. However I have managed, based on your revised MWE to put together something that approaches what you are after.

```
% memwordtocprob.tex  SE 603784

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% OP's revised MWE and my edits following my first attempt

\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,onecolumn,oneside]{memoir}
\usepackage[marginparwidth=2cm,textwidth=18.5cm,textheight=26cm]{geometry} % X
\usepackage[danish]{babel}
\usepackage[danish]{isodate}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage{comment}

\makechapterstyle{Minimal}{%
    \renewcommand*{\printchaptername}{}
    \renewcommand*{\chapternamenum}{}
    \renewcommand*{\chapnumfont}{}
    \renewcommand*{\printchapternum}{}
    \renewcommand*{\afterchapternum}{}
    \setlength{\beforechapskip}{0pt}
    \setlength{\midchapskip}{0pt}
    \setlength{\afterchapskip}{20pt}
}

\titleformat{\section}[runin]{\bfseries}{}{0pt}{}[~~]
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}
\cftpagenumbersoff{section}

\begin{comment}
\titleformat{\subsection}[runin]{\bfseries}{}{0pt}{}[~~]
\titlespacing{\subsection}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}
\end{comment}

\newcommand{\bigpar}{\vspace{1em}}

\newcommand{\Word}[1]{%
    {{\bfseries#1}\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{#1}}
}
\setsecnumdepth{chapter}

%%%% PW note the \makeatletter ... \makeatother and changes
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\setupparasubsecs}{%
  \let\oldnumberline\numberline
  \renewcommand*{\cftsubsectionfont}{\itshape}
  \renewcommand*{\cftsubsectionpagefont}{\itshape}
  \renewcommand{\l@subsection}[2]{%
%    \def\numberline####1{\textit{####1}~}%
    \def\numberline####1{\textit{####1}}%
    \leftskip=\cftsubsectionindent
    \rightskip=\@tocrmarg
%% \advance\rightskip 0pt plus \hsize % uncomment this for raggedright
%% \advance\rightskip 0pt plus 2em    % uncomment this for semi-raggedright
    \parfillskip=\fill
%    \ifhmode ,\ \else\noindent\fi
    \ifhmode,\ \else\noindent\fi
%    \ignorespaces{\cftsubsectionfont ##1}~{\cftsubsectionpagefont##2}%
    \ignorespaces{\cftsubsectionfont ##1}~%{\cftsubsectionpagefont##2}% no page numbers
    \let\numberline\oldnumberline\ignorespaces}
}
%\cftpagenumbersoff{subsection}
\makeatother

\newcommand*{\setupmaintoc}{%
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{\vspace{-1.2cm}}
\let\changetocdepth\oldchangetocdepth
\let\precistoctext\oldprecistoctext
\let\cftchapterfillnum\oldcftchapterfillnum\addtodef{\cftchapterbreak}{\par}{}
\renewcommand*{\cftchapterfont}{\normalfont\sffamily}
\renewcommand*{\cftchapterleader}{%
    \sffamily\cftdotfill{\cftchapterdotsep}}
\renewcommand*{\cftchapterafterpnum}{}
\renewcommand{\cftchapterbreak}{\par\addpenalty{-\@highpenalty}}
\setpnumwidth{2.55em}
\setrmarg{3.55em}\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}}
\let\cftpartformatpnum\oldcftpartformatpnum
\addtodef{\cftpartbreak}{\par}{}
\let\cftbookformatpnum\oldcftbookformatpnum\addtodef{\cftbookbreak}{\par}{}
%\setupparasubsecs

\begin{document}
\setupparasubsecs
\mainmatter
\chapterstyle{Minimal}

\chapter*{Title}
\begin{multicols}{2}

\setupmaintoc
\tableofcontents*
\end{multicols}
\section{Section title 1} - Date: 01.01.2011

Lorem ipsum dolor sit \Word{amet}, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in \Word{voluptate} velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
\subsection{Ut enim ad minim veniam:} Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis \Word{nostrud} exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in \Word{reprehenderit} in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non \Word{proident}, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

\section{Section title 2} - Date: 02.01.2011

Lorem ipsum dolor sit \Word{amet}, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in \Word{voluptate} velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 

Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis \Word{nostrud} exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in \Word{reprehenderit} in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non \Word{proident}, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

\section{Section title 3} - Date: 03.01.2011

Lorem ipsum dolor sit \Word{amet}, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in \Word{voluptate} velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 

Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis \Word{nostrud} exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in \Word{reprehenderit} in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non \Word{proident}, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

\section{PW section} % PW added

\end{document}  % PW added
```

[image]

I now leave it up to you to get it how you want.